# javascript - Closed tab automatically for all browser

Tags: javascript

I want to closed browser tab after pop up 'Thank you' disappeared.

```
<script language='javascript'>
alert('Thank you.'); 
window.close();
</script>
```

But It didn't works. Why???

Please to help.

**Noted: Support for all web browser.**

Thanks

Comment: can you elaborate on "didn't works"? is there an error? does it do nothing? does the alert not show?

Answer (score 1):

`window.close()` will only work on windows that were opened by JavaScript from the same origin. Otherwise it will either block it, or pop up a confirmation box asking the user if they want to allow the window to close.

There is nothing wrong with the code itself - `alert` is blocking and so will wait for the `OK` button to be pressed before continuing the script, but you need to make sure the window was opened in a valid way.